# Spring Security filters not triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have implemented an authentication/authorization mecanism in my spring java application.
This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                        .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

And those are my filters:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
      // Parse the user's credentials from the request body
      LoginRequest loginRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);

      System.out.println("loginRequest: " + loginRequest);

      // Create an authentication token with the user's credentials
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              loginRequest.getUsername(),
              loginRequest.getPassword(),
              new ArrayList<>()
      );

      // Authenticate the user
      return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the authenticated user's details
    BoUser userDetails = (BoUser) authResult.getPrincipal();

    // Create a JWT token for the user
    String token = JwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    // Add the token to the response headers
    response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
  }
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("do filter internal");
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
    else {
      String jwtToken = request.getHeader(SecParams.JWT_HEADER_NAME);
      System.out.println("jwtToken = " + jwtToken);
      if (jwtToken == null || !jwtToken.startsWith(SecParams.HEADER_PREFIX)) {
        System.out.println("null or doesn't start with Bearer");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
      }
      JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(SecParams.SECRET)).build();
      System.out.println("jwtVerifier = " + jwtVerifier);
      DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(jwtToken.substring(SecParams.HEADER_PREFIX.length()));
      System.out.println("decodedJWT = " + decodedJWT);
      String email = decodedJWT.getSubject();
      System.out.println("email = " + email);
      List<String> roles = decodedJWT.getClaims().get("roles").asList(String.class);
      System.out.println("roles = " + roles);
      Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
      roles.forEach(rn -> {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rn));
      });
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, authorities);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that those filters are not triggered when sending requests; so i still can access resources without the need to send a token in the request.

i want to know why my filters are not triggered and how to fix that

Comment: How do you know they are not triggered - have you tried settings breakpoints with a debugger? What do the logs show?

Comment: Usign System.out.println() as shown in code section above. nothing is printed so i know they are not triggered

Comment: i hope you are aware that what you have built is very unsafe. Using JWTs as sessions is very unsafe, and also spring already has handling for JWTs built in, so instead of following poor blogposts, please read the spring documentation and the chapter on JWTs

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you explain more please?

Comment: if you just google you can read all about it. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens i suggest you read about what a session is, and then read what a JWT is. JWTs are tokens they are not meant to be a session, and you are exposing yourself for the risk of session hijacking and XSS

Answer (score 0):

Your `JwtAuthorizationFilter` should be invoked for every request that matches the security configuration you've provided.

Remember that filters are configured to run in a particular order. The `OncePerRequestFilter` ensures that a specific filter is executed at most once for a single request.

However, the filter chain works in such a way that if an earlier filter in the chain has handled the request and doesn't call `doFilter` of the `FilterChain`, the later filters in the chain won't get called.

One potential issue could be related to the URL patterns you're testing. Remember that you're allowing all requests to `/login` without authentication. So, if you're testing with `/login`, your `JwtAuthorizationFilter` won't get called because you're permitting all requests to `/login`

Also, your `JwtAuthorizationFilter` is added before the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. However, the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` you've defined is added after `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` which is not the usual case in JWT authentication scenarios. Usually, `JwtAuthenticationFilter` is used instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

Comment: I'm using `/login` url to test the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and the method `attemptAuthentication()` is not called.
And i'm using other urls to test the `JwtAuthorizationFilter`.
I tried changing the order of filters 
` .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(), JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);
`  but it doesn't fix the problem